# Gmail Sidebar Gadget OAuth Origin Mismatch Error

Tags: oauth, google-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

When setting up an OAuth client id for Google APIs at [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console), you have to specify the Javascript origin if you are using Google's Javascript API for oauth. However, the Javascript origin does not support wild card urls, and I have confirmed that the server that's hosting my Gmail sidebar gadget has a different subdomain on subsequent requests. Is there a there a known solution for identifying a Gmail server as the Javascript origin, or should I proxy the OAuth requests via a service that I host?